# Display table in HTML within java

Tags: java, jquery, html

I am able to display the table but the headers are bit misaligned and shifted to right. Can someone suggest what can be missing here.

Current o/p: (Header are misaligned)

```
                Server  name ID
S1 ABC 43
S2 XYZ 67
```

Code:

```
out.append("<table id=\"dtable\" class=\"tablesorter\">");
out.append("<thead>");
out.append("<tr>");
out.append("<th>Server</th>");
out.append("<th>name</th>");
out.append("<th>ID</th>");
out.append("</tr>");
out.append("</thead>");
out.append("<tbody>");

for (String s : returns) {
  String[] s2=s.split("-");

  out.append("<tr>");
  out.append("<td>");
  for(String results : s2)
  {

    out.append(results);
    out.append("&nbsp;");
  }
  out.append("</td>");
  out.append("</tr>");
} 

out.append("</table>");
```

Comment: Do not, under any circumstances, do this in code.  You should not be creating markup in Java.  Use a templating solution (e.g. FreeMarker, Mustache, JSF with JSTL, etc.)  with CSS.

Comment: it seems you are missing `out.append("</tbody>");` after the end of the loop

Comment: Added the out.append("</tbody>") but still misaligned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add every string to separated column `td` like :

```
for (String s : returns) {
    String[] s2=s.split("-");

    out.append("<tr>");
    for(String results : s2)
    {
        out.append("<td>");
        out.append(results);
        out.append("&nbsp;");
        out.append("</td>");
    }
    out.append("</tr>");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here your creating a row and closing it “s2” times please check this:

```
    out.append("<tr>");
    out.append("<td>");
    for (String results : s2) {

        out.append(results);
        out.append("&nbsp;");
    }
    out.append("</td>");
    out.append("</tr>");
}
```

And there is no tbody close tag

Comment: Remember to give a comment when disagree 

Comment: This section of the table displays data fine. It is only the table headers that are right aligned.

Comment: This code will leads you to the invalid HTML too.. The right way to append nested HTML elements is what you looking, you'll find it in the other answer @user7471208.